# Does not closing a FileOutPutStream not write anything to the file?

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I have a function which writes the given input stream to a given output stream. Code below.

```
static void copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

The above function is called from this function

```
public static void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        try {
            **copyStream**(fis, fos);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null)
                fos.close();
        }
    } finally {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
    }
}
```

In this function, I am writing 4 MB at once. I use this function to copy images. Occasionally I see that the destination file is not created due to which an exception occurs while trying to read that file for future processing. I am guessing the culprit to be not closing the resources. Is my hypothesis good? What are the reasons why my function might fail? Please help

Comment: The file is created before this method is called so an exception here won't prevent the file being created.

Comment: Issue or no issue, you should close your resources anyway.

Comment: Agreed. I did close them. But I still was unable to figure out why accessing the copied file throws an exception occasionally( the issue is highly sporadic)

Comment: Could you provide caller method as well?

Comment: Updated the question with calling function

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that given `InputStream` and `OutputStream` installed correctly.
Add `os.flush();` at the end. Sure, both streams should be closed in the caller as well.

As alternative, you could use *Apache IO utils* `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)`.

Comment: `flush`is done automatically as part of the `close`. No need to do it explicitly unless you want to flush without closing (yet).

Comment: Yes, but I do not see caller method, therefore `flush` should help if resource is not closed correctly later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely must close your destination file to ensure that all caches from the JVM through to the OS are flushed and the file is ready for a reader to consume.

Copying large files the way that you are doing is concise in code but inefficient in operation. Consider upgrading your code to use the more efficient NIO methods, [documented here](https://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/fast-stream-copy-using-javanio-channels/) in a blog post. In case that blog disappears, here's the code:

Utility class:

```
public final class ChannelTools {
  public static void fastChannelCopy(final ReadableByteChannel src, final WritableByteChannel dest) throws IOException {
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * 1024);
    while (src.read(buffer) != -1) {
      // prepare the buffer to be drained
      buffer.flip();
      // write to the channel, may block
      dest.write(buffer);
      // If partial transfer, shift remainder down
      // If buffer is empty, same as doing clear()
      buffer.compact();
    }
    // EOF will leave buffer in fill state
    buffer.flip();
    // make sure the buffer is fully drained.
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
      dest.write(buffer);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage example with your `InputStream` and `OutputStream`:

```
// allocate the stream ... only for example
final InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
// get an channel from the stream
final ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(input);
final WriteableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(output);
// copy the channels
ChannelTools.fastChannelCopy(inputChannel, outputChannel);
// closing the channels
inputChannel.close();
outputChannel.close()
```

There is also a more concise method documented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)) that achieves the same thing with less code:

```
// Getting file channels
FileChannel in = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(target).getChannel();

// JavaVM does its best to do this as native I/O operations.
in.transferTo(0, in.size(), out);

// Closing file channels will close corresponding stream objects as well.
out.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the importance of flip and compact. But why will the copy fail so sporadically? I mean this function fails once in 10000 times may be. What is the reason it could fail?

Comment: Is your reader synchronized with the writer? How does the reader know when the writer has finished completely? If it's monitoring a directory for files appearing then you have a potential race condition.

Comment: No, it is not within the same flow we write a file to a new location and try to read it somewhere down the line in the code. I guess you are right it is a race condition. Thank you for your time